# UIWebView opens non-related site

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I opened a website by using `UIWebview`, but some times when I clicked on a button or a link, it automatically calls a non-related website. E.g. when I click on a Facebook link, it goes directly to the App Store and asks for Facebook installation process (even if Facebook app is installed). After that I can't go back in my app. So I have to exit and re-open my app.

- *Why is it moving to the App Store even if Facebook app is already installed?*
- *Is there any possibility to add a back option to the App Store?*

**Code:**

```
webviews.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
[webviews loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL of the web site"]]];
webviews.scalesPageToFit =YES;
```

Comment: Make sure that the facebook app is of latest version

Comment: Link example, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebview delegate to control what the webview can or can't open (check ....shouldStartLoadWithRequest:...)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html